# Maintain one-at-a-time pipeline processing when storing output in an intermediary variable

Tags: powershell

By way of illustration, here is a function that outputs ten integers.

```
function Foo { for($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) { Write-Host Inner $i; $i; }}
```

When we call `Foo` as follows, `Foo` iterates only five times. That's what we want.

```
Foo | Select-Object -First 5
```

When we call `Foo` like this, `Foo` iterates all ten times. That's what we want to avoid.

```
$foo = Foo; $foo | Select-Object -First 5;
```

Sometimes an intermediary variable is useful for readability.

How, if at all, can we maintain PowerShells one-at-a-time processing when we using an intermediary variable?

---

On request, here is an elaboration of why we might want to do this in the real world. It is still convoluted, but it gets across the idea. The following outputs the first name of a `public struct` type in a C# file that is under version control.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | 
 Where-Object { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName ".git") } | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
   Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.cs | 
    Get-Content | 
     Select-String "public struct" |
      Select-Object -First 1;
```

It's a fine query, but arguably an explanatory variable or two would be useful.

```
$gitRepositories = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | 
 Where-Object { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName ".git") };

$csharpFiles = $gitRepositories | 
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
  Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.cs 

$structNames = $csharpFiles | 
 Get-Content | 
  Select-String "public struct" |
   Select-Object -First 1;
```

When wrapped with `Measure-Command`, the first query takes 8.5 seconds and the second query take several minutes.

Comment: Wouldn't having an argument on your function that could limit the number of iterations make sense in this case?

Comment: That would work in some cases. Consider though the case in which we might want to run `CTRL + C` to stop processing after we see some output that we seek. Under the covers, `Select-Object -First 5` stops processing in a way that is similar to how `CTRL + C` stops processing. It was easier to write `Select-Object` in the question, though, so I did that instead.

Comment: I see the point. One thing I can comment on (I might be wrong), if you stop the processing with `CTRL+C` then `$foo = Foo` will not work on PowerShell, you would end up with an empty variable or with variable that has the output from the previous run of said function. In this case, it would be a better approach to add values to an `arraylist` or `generic list` depending on the need, that way you would not loose the output of the function's current run after stopping the pipeline manually. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your function an advanced function, by way of `[CmdletBinding()]`, like this:

```
function Foo { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    for($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) { 
        Write-Host Inner $i; $i; 
    }
}
```

Then you gain access to the automatic parameter `-OutVariable`, and now you can do this:

```
Foo -OutVariable foo | Select-Object -First 5

$foo
```

Of course, in your example, you could just as easily do:

```
$foo = Foo | Select-Object -First 5
```

So I'm not certain exactly what you want, but I do suspect that `-OutVariable` fits the bill better, because it is populated as the pipeline goes.

So for example:

```
function Foo { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    for($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) { 
        Write-Host Inner $i; $i;
        sleep -s 2 
    }
}
```

(now the function sleeps 2 seconds on every iteration)

If you then <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in the middle of it, `$foo` will contain what was produced so far.

---

With further comments, I think I see what you're after now: a return value from the function that can be enumerated later. This is an Enumerator.

There are two complications to returning one from your function:

1. PowerShell tends to automatically "unroll" (process) these on return, but you can probably get around this with the classic trick of returning a single element array, where the element is the enumerator.
2. Creating the enumerator without pre-processing all the items though is going to be dependent on the specifics of it.

To create an enumerator you'll need to create a type (a class) that inherits from `IEnumerator`. You can make this class do whatever you want so that's where the complication of the implementation will go.

Your function then will really just serve as a PowerShell interface to instantiating and returning such a thing.

```
class MyEnumerator : System.Collections.IEnumerator
{
    hidden [int] $index;
    hidden [int] $max;
    hidden [int] $start;
    hidden [int] $item;

    MyEnumerator([int]$max, [int]$start=0) {
        $this.index = -1
        $this.start = $start
        $this.max = $max
    }
    [bool] MoveNext() {
        ++$this.index
        $this.item = $this.index + $this.start

        # demonstration
        if ($this.item -gt 7) {
            throw
        }

        return ($this.item -le $this.max) 
    }

    [void] Reset() {
        $this.index = -1
    }

    [object] get_Current() {
        return $this.item
    }
}

function Foo ($start, $max) {
    ,[MyEnumerator]::new($max, $start)
}
```

So here in this example, I've created this enumerator class, and you can give it any start and max integer value for it to enumerate through. But I threw in a little catch in that it's hardcoded to throw an exception if the item value is greater than 7.

The function creates the enumerator and returns it (notice the unary comma for making a single element array).

So you can run this like so:

```
$foo = Foo 2 10

# no exception!

$foo | Select -First 5

# no exception!
```

This on the other hand:

```
$foo = Foo 2 10
$foo
# will throw
```

(you've attempted to enumerate through the whole thing, implicitly)

One thing you need to be aware of is that `$foo` is the enumerator object, and keeps state, and now you need to be responsible for that if you're trying to "re-use" it.

Example:

```
$foo = Foo 2 10
$foo | Select -First 5

$foo.Current
# 6

$foo | Select -First 5
# 7
# exception!
```

You can use `$foo.Reset()` to make it go back to the beginning.

---

Another alternative: returning a function (or just a script block) from a function.

This one won't behave as naturally as the enumerator, but it'll be easier to implement.

```
function Foo {
    {
        for($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) { Write-Host Inner $i; $i; }
    }
}

$foo = Foo ; & $foo | Select-Object -First 5
```

For this, since the return value is a script block, you'll have to execute it before piping it along.

I imagine what you were really looking for was the enumerator, but you can see that that will require some heavier lifting to implement.

---

Ok so now seeing your more realistic examples from your edit:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | 
 Where-Object { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName ".git") } | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
   Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.cs | 
    Get-Content | 
     Select-String "public struct" |
      Select-Object -First 1;
```

vs

```
$gitRepositories = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | 
 Where-Object { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName ".git") };

$csharpFiles = $gitRepositories | 
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
  Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.cs 

$structNames = $csharpFiles | 
 Get-Content | 
  Select-String "public struct" |
   Select-Object -First 1;
```

I actually still don't see the point of the intermediate variables here. You're kind of fighting the tool. I don't really think they add much to readability, and as you've already seen, they harm performance.

That said, for finding files and directories, you can almost do exactly what you want.

Here's a replacement for the first part, `$gitRepositories`:

```
$initialPath = Get-Location
$top = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($initialPath)

$gitRepositories = $top.EnumerateDirectories('.git', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
```

In this example, `$gitRepositories` will be an enumerable, so it will not enumerate the directories until forced to. You could use it with `foreach` or just try to display it and at that moment it will go through the tree. Those things in PowerShell know how to deal with enumerables already; that is, they call `.GetEnumerator()` automatically and use the resulting enumerator.

You can do that yourself too, `$e = $gitRepositories.GetEnumerator()` and then making calls to `$e.MoveNext()` and `$e.Current`, etc.

But the part where this will start to break down is your second one:

```
$csharpFiles = $gitRepositories | 
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
  Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.cs
```

The issue here is that you need to enumerate the first completely, in order to get the next enumerable, so as soon as you want this intermediate one, you will lose the "lazy" aspect for the first completely.

The other issue is that there isn't just one directory on which to call `.EnumerateFiles()`; `$gitRepositories` can contain many directories and you need to enumerate the files of each one, so you can't even "take the hit" of enumerating `$gitRepositories` and end up with a single enumerable as the result... at least not without creating some kind of enumerable class of your own that accepts a list of enumerables and then enumerates them all in sequence, providing a "virtual" single enumerable.

**All that being said** while this approach can't give you *exactly* what you are looking for, in general the `[DirectoryInfo]` object's `.Enumerate*` methods are quite useful, and very performant, and the resultant `[DirecotryInfo]` and/or `[FileInfo]` obejcts are also chock full of useful properties and methods, providing nearly all the functionality of the objects returned from the PowerShell-native cmdlets, so you should consider using these in general!

---

The last option I have for you is kind of nuts, and it's not going to make any of your code easier to read or  understand, that's for sure.

Unlike your initial sample functions, the commands you're trying to run in your more real-world example are true cmdlets that support begin/process/end. The "process" part (what would correspond to a `Process {}` block in an advanced function) does sort of act an enumerator in a pipeline.

You can actually create some objects that let you call commands with fine-grained control over running those pieces. This is how "proxy functions" work, which is also how implicit remoting works.

You can have PowerShell generate such a proxy command for you, with `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create()`.

```
$gci = Get-Command Get-ChildItem
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($gci)
```

The result will be this big blob of stuff:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Items', SupportsTransactions=$true, HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308')]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Items', Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]
    ${Path},

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralItems', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string[]]
    ${LiteralPath},

    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [string]
    ${Filter},

    [string[]]
    ${Include},

    [string[]]
    ${Exclude},

    [Alias('s')]
    [switch]
    ${Recurse},

    [uint32]
    ${Depth},

    [switch]
    ${Force},

    [switch]
    ${Name})


dynamicparam
{
    try {
        $targetCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet, $PSBoundParameters)
        $dynamicParams = @($targetCmd.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Where-Object { $_.Value.IsDynamic })
        if ($dynamicParams.Length -gt 0)
        {
            $paramDictionary = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
            foreach ($param in $dynamicParams)
            {
                $param = $param.Value

                if(-not $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.ContainsKey($param.Name))
                {
                    $dynParam = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new($param.Name, $param.ParameterType, $param.Attributes)
                    $paramDictionary.Add($param.Name, $dynParam)
                }
            }
            return $paramDictionary
        }
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

begin
{
    try {
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
        {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }
        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

process
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

end
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
<#

.ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

#>
```

The important bits for you are all around creating a "steppable pipeline" around the command, which would let you call `.Process()` yourself; that is to invoke individual iterations of the process pipeline.

In theory you could cobble together some sort of wrapper function, specialized enumerable class, etc. that could result in single "variables" that let you lazily enumerate through pipelines.

I consider this more of a thought exercise than something practical though.

Comment: I think he is looking for a function that will output to a variable even if the script is manually stopped, which your last code should cover and is quite ingenious however it would be quite slow on a large data set and I don't see why OP wouldn't use a collection or arraylist created outside the scope of the function.

Comment: This is neat but it still eagerly pulls all the items into memory before piping. In other words, running `Foo -OutVariable $bar; $bar | Select-Object -first 5;` writes all ten items to the host whereas `Foo -OutVariable $bar | Select-Object -first 5;` writes only five items to the host.

Comment: By the way, I appreciate that the example is a contrived minimal reproduction, but that semi-colon in the question is essential.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon What I am looking for is not what you think; I do not seek a function that will output to a variable even if the script is manually stopped. What I seek instead is to use a variable as an intermediary between two pipeline steps, while maintaining one-at-a-time processing along that pipeline. Instead of running `Foo | Bar`, I would like to run `$foo = Foo; $foo | Bar;` as two separate expressions, and to stream the output through the variable instead of buffering the output in the variable.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin powershell is processing the code in sequence unless you're using multithreading i.e.: runspace. When you do `$foo = Foo; $foo | Bar` , `$foo | Bar` will only be ran when `$foo = Foo` has finished.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That makes sense; thank you for talking me through it. If I understand correctly, there is no magic that prevents `$foo = Foo;` from buffering the entire output in the `$foo` variable.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin maybe there is and I could not be aware of, hopefully you can find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I see now; what you really wanted was an enumerator/enumerable. I've edited with some solutions, but not sure you'll end up wanting to use them in the end. What would be helpful is to get a better idea of _why_ you want to use an intermediate variable, when there's no purpose to do so in the example. A real-world reason to do that might be helpful to understand the path forward. I have one other possible thing to demonstrate, but before I take the time, knowing what you want would be appreciated...

Comment: @briantist I added a real world-ish example to my question. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine for the actual objects you collect in `$foo` - which is an array of integers 0 - 9. The Write-Host will always output to the console*.

With your example the output is

```
Inner 0
Inner 1
Inner 2
Inner 3
Inner 4
Inner 5
Inner 6
Inner 7
Inner 8
Inner 9
0
1
2
3
4
```

As you can see the select-object -first 5 worked just fine, selecting 0 - 4.

So to clarify, your entire function is being run to completion when you run

```
$foo = Foo
```

That outputs the 10 write-host statements.

```
Inner 0
Inner 1
Inner 2
Inner 3
Inner 4
Inner 5
Inner 6
Inner 7
Inner 8
Inner 9
```

Then `Select-Object -First 5` selects the 5 objects.

```
$foo | Select-Object -First 5

0
1
2
3
4
```

---

* Unless redirected to another stream

Comment: I could have been more clear in my question. What I am trying to achieve is to prevent `Foo` from loading the entire array into memory. When it runs through a pipeline, one-at-a-time processing happens, which does not load the entire array into memory. When it runs into a variable, though, the entire array loads into memory. I am wondering whether we can maintain one-at-a-time processing when using an intermediary variable.

Comment: Write host will always write to the console, not store in your variable. When you run $foo = Foo  that is a single command by itself. It will run the entire function. The semicolon makes them two completely different commands. You’re basically asking for the capability of the second command to go back in time and fix your first command to stop after 5.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I am looking for deferred execution, which is kind of like the capability of the second command to go back in time. I have my doubts that this is possible.

Comment: Perhaps in other situations, but this one is ruined by write host. If you don’t care about polluting the output you could use write-output or drop it altogether. Doubt that’s ideal.

Comment: The `Write-Host` is not essential to the question. It is there only for explanatory purposes. Another way of posing it is like this: `function Foo { for($i = 0; $i -lt 1000000000000000000; $i++) { $i; } }`. In that case, running `Foo | Select -First 1` returns immediately, but running `$foo = Foo; $foo | Select-First 1` returns only after all zillion iterations have completed.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is doing what you tell it to.  The loop already runs 10 times during the assignment statement.  The write-host output doesn't get stored in the $foo variable.  This seems like the only way to get the output you want, having select-object kill the loop while it's actually running.  Write-host output never goes in the pipeline anyway.

```
$foo = Foo | Select-Object -First 5

Inner 0
Inner 1
Inner 2
Inner 3
Inner 4


$foo

0
1
2
3
4
```

```
1..10 | % { write-host num $_ } | select -first 5

num 1
num 2
num 3
num 4
num 5
num 6
num 7
num 8
num 9
num 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Briantists answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69654146/1108891), here is a shorthand that fills the requirements.

```
$foo = { Foo }; & $foo | Select-Object -First 5;
```

Wrapping `Foo` in `{ }` defers execution, prevents complete iteration, and maintains one-at-a-time processing. Woot! Thanks Briantist!

[image: ![enter image description here]